# Website functionality tips

Tags: web, projects-and-solutions

I'm writing a paper about website functionality so far I've covered some of them :

1. Event Calendars and Registration, and Appointment Setting
2. Product Databases and Wizard-like applications
3. Flash and other Interactive Multimedia Presentations
4. Online Publishing and Article Modules
5. Surveys and Interactive tools that entice Feedback
6. Content Management Tools

This is a research project(sophomore year project), can anyone help me to add some more items to the list, I just need functionality I'll google the rest. Thank you

Comment: Define "website functionality."

Comment: You need to learn to make yourself clear. What is the subject of your project?

Comment: define website functionality. The possibilities are endless. You've just listed a couple things that some websites may or may not have. What constitutes them as "website functionality"?

Comment: website functionality, like web site features, maybe web site modules is better way to say ..

Comment: ex for SO website functionality : open source ads, user login with openid, user voting, user comments etc ..

Comment: How about "updating patient medical records"? That would be website functionality for a site used to update patient medical records.

Comment: @John Saunders true , but it is too specific .. refering to functionality of a some medical / or related websites .. I was looking for more general things

Comment: @Gandalf: my point was your question is too general

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're talking about more bog-standard websites, rather than specialty sites, I would add the following to your list:

Authentication and Authorization
Analytics
Communication
Administration

Answer (score 1):

User account and profile management